# How can I use the Log Parser Plugin in a "scripted" Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The snippet generator says to use something like this:

```
step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher', failBuildOnError: true,
      showGraphs: true, useProjectRule: false])
```

Will this work in a scripted pipeline, or is it only for declarative pipelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be as easy as

```
try {
  node {
       echo 'Error: oh no'
  }
} finally {
  node {
   step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher', parsingRulesPath: '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins-rule-logparser', useProjectRule: false])
  }
}
```